# Python how to send multiple strings as input to script when prompted

Tags: python

My script takes username and password from the prompt when executed. I am able to send a single string as input but unable to send multiple strings based on condition. Can someone help me how to achieve this or if any alternate approach is also fine? I have tried following ways.

```
import sys
import StringIO
import getpass
class ProxyDetails:
    def __init__(self,option):
        self.option = option
        self.proxy_option = self.get_web_proxy_details()
        self.call_request()
        self.parse_test()

    def get_web_proxy_details(self):
        if self.option == "Default":
            self.proxy_username = getpass.getpass("Enter Username for Proxy : ")
            self.proxy_password = getpass.getpass("Enter Password for Proxy : ")
            print "self.proxy_username is {} ".format(self.proxy_username)
            print "self.proxy_password is {} ".format(self.proxy_password)
        else:
            print("proxy is none ")

    def call_request(self):
        # this method will do API call
        pass
    def parse_test(self):
        #this method will parse the json
        pass

f1 = sys.stdin
f = StringIO.StringIO('admin')
f = StringIO.StringIO('admin123')
sys.stdin = f
obj=ProxyDetails(option="Default")
sys.stdin = f1
```

Another way

```
f = StringIO.StringIO('admin','\n','admin123')
sys.stdin=f
```

Another way

```
f = StringIO.StringIO('admin','admin123')
sys.stdin=f
```

Comment: You can do something like this: 1) create text file with data you want send to input 2) add in your code `input = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdin.buffer, encoding='utf-8')` 3) run your's script with pipe  `cat data.txt | python main.py` 4) iterate over the input `for line in input: ...`.

Answer (score 0):

1. The getpass you use, does not read from stdin by default:
   https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html
2. The the two assignments to f will overwrite each other.
   `sys.stdin = StringIO.StringIO('admin','\n','admin123')`
   is more likely to do the job. You can try this out using stdin.read() instead of getpass.getpass().